# Problem: WPF Checkbox inside Listbox is disabled but still clickable

Tags: wpf, checkbox

I have a Style for a listbox, using checkboxes. I want to bind the isEnabled property of each checkbox to a property (ItemEnabled) of each item. This is my code:

```
<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />                    
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <CheckBox Focusable="False"                                    
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent} }"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ItemEnabled, Mode=OneWay}">
                                    <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                                </CheckBox>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

So far, the checkboxes which have the property ItemEnabled set to false, are grayed out. However, still clickable and checkable/uncheckable.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to control the checkbox 'IsEnabled' controlled via model, 'IsChecked' controlled by selection of listview selection.

You can do by simply creating DataTemplate for your model

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding ItemEnabled}"
            IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem},Path=IsSelected}"
                  ></CheckBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

TestModel:

```
public class Emp
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool ItemEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Remove the 'ItemContainerStyle' from your code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, RajN.
I managed to solve it based on your comment.
Here is the new XAML:

```
<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Focusable="False"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem} }"
                                      IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ItemEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"
                                      Content="{Binding Path=ItemName, Mode=OneWay}">
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```